# How to invoke a method when a module is loaded?

Tags: javascript, module, ecmascript-6

I'd like to compose a demo showing the order of loading of modules. Supposed there are two modules *Uno* and *Duo* and I'd like to print their names to the console **as they're loaded**. How can I do that? I'm talking about the following pseudo-code.

**Uno.js**

```
import Duo from "./duo.js";
default export {
  loaded: () => { console.log("Uno loaded"); }
}
```

**Duo.js**

```
default export {
  loaded: () => { console.log("Duo loaded"); }
}
```

I've tried a couple of wild shots like *loaded*, *init*, *start* etc. but didn't get any print outs. Then, I goolearched it for a while but didn't see any examples showing anything related except for e.g. Vue framework where the event seems to be build in. Adding the term *construct* produces a wave of comparisons between modules and prototypes.

Usually, when there's no tons of examples on how to, it implies that it's not possible to achieve. However, since I haven't found any statements contradicting that it's doable, I'm still a bit hopeful.

I've seen the approach [chaining the `require`and subsequent statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16770425/run-action-after-all-requirejs-modules-are-loaded) but in my case, I want specifically the module itself to be self-containedly verbose.

Comment: Default-exporting object literals is a bad idea. Instead, use named exports: `export function loaded() { … }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are currently exporting a function that does what you want from the module. Which means someone would need to invoke that function, and no, there's no automatic hook that invokes an exported item with a certain name when a module is loaded.

Instead, simply call the function yourself right in the module body. When the module is being evaluated, you are free to perform any side effects that you want:

```
// uno.js
import "./duo.js";
console.log("Uno loaded");
```

```
// duo.js
console.log("Duo loaded");
```

Comment: Great to have that explicitly stated. I have a follow-up on your alteration of my import call. You omit the keyword `from` as well as the name of what it's being imported as. How come? Is it equivalent to importing anonymously when we won't be needing a reference to the import made? Or is it some kind of short-hand I'm not aware of?

Comment: Yes, since my modified `duo.js` doesn't export anything any more, I'm not importing anything from it (I don't need any identifier `Uno` anywhere). The import just makes sure that the other module is already loaded.

Comment: Great! +1 for the elaboration. I'm curious now, is there a reasonable scenario where we'd like a module to be loaded **but** don't wish to refer to it? I can possibly imagine that importing my CSS's from a SASS file requires no naming of the results. Is that correct? What about JS files? Any non-weird case when we want to import a chunk of JavaScript but then not use the reference to it?

Comment: Yes, some frameworks let you "import" non-JS-files that they will bundle together, and for JS files there's the use case of init files that set up some global variables or doing things (just like the logs in the example) without exporting anything that would need to be explicitly imported. Yes, I'd consider these code smells :-)